How to exclude 'aggFunc' row from the excel export in Ag-grid
Is there a way to exclude bottom row which displays results of aggFunc a column from the excel export.
Essentially, I want to display average on the screen but want to exclude it when exported as that file will be used to import data elsewhere.
Plunker example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/S6tgvSC91MxdGQcZ
Screenshot of the screen and export xls

I already tried searching various options on the ag-grid documentation

Tried skipFooters and skipPinnedBottom options


